# How to create Tkinter LabelFrame class?

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to have a list of labels which are placed inside label frame instances from a list which are placed inside notebooks from a list and so on..

The window appears and the notebook tabs are placed. I can also individually add Tkinter LabelFrames to a notebook tab and then individually add labels to each label frame but this is not efficient at all.

At this point I cannot seem to discover why the LabelFrame instance will not appear in the tab. Is the `MyLabelFrames` class created correctly? Is the instance being created correctly? I cannot find docs on creating LabelFrame classes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from HH_search import HandHistory


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Hand History Equilibrium Analyzer")
        self.geometry('900x700')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        names = ['Hand History Analyzer', 'Tree Loader']
        frames = ['Hand History', 'Solver']
        hh_labels = ['Info:', 'Players:', 'Pre-flop:',
                     'Flop:', 'Turn:', 'River:']

        self.nb = self.create_notebook(names)
        self.menu = self.create_menus()
        self.frame = self.create_frames(frames)

        tree_tab = self.nb.tabs['Tree Loader']
        positions = ['BTN', 'CO', 'MP', 'EP', 'SB', 'BB']

        var = tk.StringVar()
        var.set(positions[0])

        for player in positions:
            ttk.Radiobutton(
                tree_tab, text=player, variable=var,
                value=player, command=False).grid(column=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.mainloop()

    def create_notebook(self, names):
        nb = MyNotebook(self, names)
        nb.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        hh_tab = nb.tabs['Hand History Analyzer']

        hh_btn = ttk.Button(
            hh_tab, text='Begin Hand History Analysis',
            command=lambda: HandHistory.analyze_hand(self))
        hh_btn.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        return nb

    def create_menus(self):
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        sub_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=sub_menu)
        sub_menu.add_separator()
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.destroy)
        return menu

    def create_frames(self, frames):
        frm = MyLabelFrames(self, frames)
        frm.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        frame1 = frm.frames['Hand History']

        lbltest1 = ttk.Label(frame1, text='test')
        lbltest1.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        return frm


class MyNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, master, names):
        super().__init__(master, width=897, height=675)
        self.tabs = {}
        for name in names:
            self.tabs[name] = tab = ttk.Frame(self)
            self.add(tab, text=name)


class MyLabelFrames(ttk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, frames):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.frames = {}
        for frame in frames:
            self.frames[frame] = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text=frames)


GUI()
```

Comment: This code looks complicated. Can you get it to work without this heavy use of classes? If so, that is a good solution. Or as Jack Diederich says: "the signature of this is not a class is that it has two methods, one of which is `__init__()`" (in [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) ).

Comment: You create your `LabelFrame` within the `root` Window == `MyLabelFrames(self, frames)`. If you want to place it inside a **Notebook Tab Frame**, you have to use `MyLabelFrames(<Notebook Tag Frame object>, frames)`. Second, it's not enought to do `frm.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)`, your `LabelFrame` is created, but not expanded. Read about [row/columnconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: @figbeam The goal was to create classes so everything is more neatly organized and easier to change later on e.g. one list of labels versus several

@stovfl Ahh yes, I should `expand=both, fill=true` i believe. Is it not smart to put the LabelFrames within classes and use lists for everything?

Comment: I understand. However; over-use of classes tend to make things more complicated, as Jack Diederich explains in his talk.

Comment: The `MyLabelFrames` is hidden due to the height of the main window is too short.  Try reduce the height of `Notebook` (currently 675 pixel high) or increase that of the main window (currently 700 pixel high).